# Understanding how to do threaded alpha beta search

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, chess, alpha-beta-pruning

I am creating a chess engine and I want to add more of a speedup by adding threads.

I have tried looking at open source engines (stockfish, etc) and https://www.chessprogramming.org/Parallel_Search, but I do not understand how they use threads to speed up the search.

Can you explain how engines add threading to the search or any other resources that help?

thanks

Comment: Good question, wish I knew but seems way too complicated to keep track of and to bug search for my level unfortunately..

Comment: The current threaded algorithm for Stockfish is "lazy SMP", and is said to be easy to implement and efficient. However, I couldn't find any ressources on that, unfortunately... The only thing I found is a simplified ABDADA which gives correct results : I got a x3 speed-up when using 4 cores. See http://www.tckerrigan.com/Chess/Parallel_Search/Simplified_ABDADA/